# Are there any Official/UA magic items intended for use in a mass support role?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, helping

More precisely, magical items that are capable of assisting allies. The goal is the ability to choose multiple targets in a turn, rather than only one. An example item would be the Banner of the Krig Rune, or something with an effect akin to spells such as Mass Cure Wounds or Mass Teleport.

My research thus far has only turned up the aforementioned Banner of the Krig Rune, as it seems magic items are designed with the intent of only the owner in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There are many items that can directly target multiple allies

Obviously you can use *a lot* of items to assist allies, even a *+1 sword* is assisting allies when you use it to fight a common enemy.

There are also many items, like a *Daern's Instant Fortress* or *Carpet of Flying* or *Folding Boat* that can benefit multiple creatures, or many items that summon creatures, create illusions, damage enemies, shed light etc, that will not just benefit the wearer but all of the characters equally.

But your question seems to be more specifically, if there are magic items that buff or bolster or directly affect multiple creatures, instead of just the wearer. Again there are many. Without trying to be exhaustive, just from browsing the core rules briefly:

- **Candle of Invocation**. *While lit, the candle sheds dim light in a 30-foot radius. Any creature within that light whose alignment matches that of the candle makes attack rolls, saving throws, and ability checks with advantage.*
- **Dust of Disappearance** *When you use an action to throw the dust into the air, you and each creature and object within 10 feet ofyou become invisible for 2d4 minutes.*
- **Helm of Teleportation** *While wearing it, you can use an action and expend 1 charge to cast the teleport spell from it.* (*Teleport* affects you and up to eight willing creatures).
- **Rod of Alertness** *As an action, you can plant the haft end of the rod in the ground, whereupon the rod's head sheds bright light in a 60-foot radius and dim light for an additional 60 feet. While in that bright light, you and any creature that is friendly to you gain a +1 bonus to AC and saving throws and can sense the location of any invisible hostile creature that is also in the bright light.*
- **Rod of Security** *The rod then instantly transports you and up to 199 other willing creatures you can see to a paradise that exists in an extraplanar space.*
- **Spell Scrolls** of any of the spells like *Aid, Bless, Mass Cure Wounds* that buff multiple allies.

As a last point, 5e is not big on the online massively multiplayer RPG concepts of roles like DPS, healer/buffer, tank and so on like 4e was. While you certainly can build characters with those in mind, and play a tactical combat / optimization game like that, the DMG suggests a much broader play experience (p. 6) including in addition to combat also Acting, Exploring, Investigating, Problem Solving and Storytelling.

Comment: Thank you for the assist, and the note about 5e. The character in development is a Shepherd Druid who provides the tactical combat support for the other players, and maintains capability more in the other play experiences.